# Getting errors packaging a working Spring Tool Suit app

Tags: spring-boot, maven, sts, crud-repository

I wrote a Spring Boot app on Spring Tools Suite which is working fine on STS. It is an example from Spring In Action Fifth Edition (by the way, book's code is plenty of bugs). But when I tried to pack it on a jar file, Maven suddenly start to throw compiling errors. Basically messages are:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project taco-cloud: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 

[ERROR] /Users/lm2a/mmxx/sts-workspace/taco-cloud/src/main/java/tacos/data/JdbcTacoRepository.java:[18,8] tacos.data.JdbcTacoRepository is not abstract and does not override abstract method deleteAll() in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

[ERROR] /Users/lm2a/mmxx/sts-workspace/taco-cloud/src/main/java/tacos/data/JdbcIngredientRepository.java:[14,8] tacos.data.JdbcIngredientRepository is not abstract and does not override abstract method deleteAll() in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

[ERROR] /Users/lm2a/mmxx/sts-workspace/taco-cloud/src/main/java/tacos/data/JdbcIngredientRepository.java:[31,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

[ERROR] /Users/lm2a/mmxx/sts-workspace/taco-cloud/src/main/java/tacos/data/JdbcOrderRepository.java:[19,8] tacos.data.JdbcOrderRepository is not abstract and does not override abstract method deleteAll() in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
```

Its supposed on Spring Data JPA we can use an interface (CrudRepository) which we don't need to implement and it will provide us with a lot of CRUD methods. This fact and the fact it is running smoothly on STS (and there are not complains about any methods not implemented) make me feel lost.
Any help would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Please forget this question. It was just my mistake, some of the JDBC implementations (Early examples in Chapter 3) remains in my JPA project, and being that classes were implementing some CRUD methods, seems as it was the source of the errors. Apologize me.